# Is it true that any norm could be taken to be the definition of differentiation on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $||\cdot||$ be the 2-norm.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function.

Then we define $f'(x)=A$ if $0=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah||}{||h||}$.

If i take a different norm other than 2-norm, then would the unique linear transformation $A$ differ?

If not, how do i prove it?

If so, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Btw, I know that in finite-dimensional vector space, every norm is topologically equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take another norm, say $||\cdot||_1$. Then because indeed al norms are equivalent there exist $k,K$ such that $k||x||_1 \le ||x|| \le K||x||_1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. It then follows that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{k}{K}\frac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah||_1}{||h||_1} \le\frac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah||}{||h||} \le \frac{K}{k}\frac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah||_1}{||h||_1}.
\end{equation}
Similarly we can bound the differential with respect to the $||\cdot||_1$ norm to the one with respect to the $||\cdot||$ norm. So we can conclude that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah||_1}{||h||_1} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah||}{||h||} = 0.
\end{equation}